# margins of book class

Tags: margins

I would like to know what are the margins (top, right,bottom and left; in meters) that are by default assigned for the`book` class. Is there a command or a way to know them?

Comment: LaTeX model is different: it doesn't specify the four margins, but rather many more dimensions and deduces the bottom and right (outer) margins from them. With the `layout` package suggested by Gonzalo Medina you'll see those dimensions. The unit is "printer points": 72.27pt = 1in = 2.54cm

Comment: The answer depends importantly on the text font size (`10pt` (default), `11pt`, and `12pt`) and on whether the output is set in single-column or two-column format. To find LaTeX's default values of the margins for each combination of these main options, either use the `layout` package (as is explained in @GonzaloMedina's answer) or open the files `bk10.clo`, `bk11.clo`, and `bk12.clo` files (`.clo` is short for "class option") manually and search for the relevant parameters. I recommend using the `layout` package...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To produce an overview of the layout of the current document, you can use the `\layout` command from the [layout](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layout) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

The ouput is a two page document showing this:

[image]

[image]

Another option would be to use the [layouts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{layouts}

\newcommand\DocLength[1]{%
  The value for \texttt{#1} is \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\csname#1\endcsname}\par}
\begin{document}

\DocLength{evensidemargin}
\DocLength{oddsidemargin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `\pagevalues` command you will obtain a table of the values
of the current document’s page layout parameters; this, together with the `showframe` option for the `geometry` package, can be useful when designing a new page layout. A little example with some "extreme" values just for illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=12cm,paperwidth=18cm,includehead,includefoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\printinunitsof{cm}

\begin{document}
\pagevalues
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But If I'm not satisfied of margins of my document how can I set them to myself using cm as unit of measure?

Comment: @Mazzy: if you are talking about changing the predefined layout, then use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. For example, `\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}` will give you 3cm margins.

Comment: Suppose I would change the margin in this way: odd pages=margin top,bottom,left=3cm and right=3.5cm.even pages=margin top,right,bottom=3cm and left=3.5cm.

Comment: @Mazzy Then you could use something like `\usepackage[vmargin=3cm,rmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=3cm]{geometry}` and probably you'll need some other options depending on whether the header/footer are to be included or not in the margins. Read the package documentation to learn all the options it offers.

Comment: @Mazzy I think you are leaving that `3.5cm` margin for binding. If so use `\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.5cm,margin=3cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @HarishKumar yes for binding.right!!!thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Gonzalo The image links appear to be broken!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on whether you want to include the header/footer and possibly even if you use `twoside` document. Perhaps the following minimal working example can be a start:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{layouts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts
\begin{document}
\pagevalues
\end{document}
```

uses the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) to produce

[image]

All units are printed in points by default, and there are 0.0351459 points per cm. Note that LaTeX does not use metres as a valid length.