# Print margins of a document

Tags: margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [margins of book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50258/margins-of-book-class)

Suppose I have a tex file with uses some document class and some packages which might control the margins of the document hidden to me as user (perhaps the document class sets the margins using the `geometry` package or via `typearea` or in an other way, let us assume, that we don't know). Is there any way to print the actual page margins (top, bottom, left, right) of the document? It would be enough to get this as compiler output.

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate question, you can use the geometry key `showlayout=true` or use the `layouts` or `layout` package. You can also see any parameter by typing `\show\textwidth` etc...

Comment: If you `\usepackage{showframe}`, you will see the print margins on each page, similar to the `showframe` option of [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: Thanks. The `layout` package helps. I guess that this is independent of the way, the layout was set (as described in my question)?