# Text not aligned from a page to another

Tags: margins

Every page, the text is not aligned.

**EXPLICATION**

```
First page 
 Text
 Text
 Text
 Text 

Next page
   Text
   Text
   Text
   Text

Next page 
 Text
 Text
 Text
 Text
```

Comment: This is normal behavior for some document classes, and has to do with leaving extra space for the binding.  Try using the [oneside] option for \documentclass.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not only with extra space for the binding but alternating margins for double sided documents with inner margin (sum of right margin of left page and left margin of right page) approx the outer margin.

Comment: Actually i'm working on a thesis template (writing my master thesis), it's the bredel template, but i don't understand why it's behaving like that. I tried \documentclass[oneside]{book} but it doesn't work

Comment: Do please tell us which document class you use, and do tell us which options you specify at the `\documentclass` stage. Please also clarify what "it doesn't work" entails.

Comment: Related: [Modern book design, margins and typed area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55502/modern-book-design-margins-and-typed-area),  [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins), [margins of book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50258/margins-of-book-class)

Comment: I found the probleme. I had this: `\LoadClass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{book}` just wrote oneside instead of two side and it's ok now thank you guys!

Comment: @Schweinebacke I set margins with this `\RequirePackage[inner=20mm,outer=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}`