# What is the default margin and font title and text size of this LaTeX document?

Tags: formatting, margins, fontsize, text

What are the default margin (in inches) and font title and text size of this  LaTeX document template I found? I can't seem to find a certain answer.
[image: Acceleration in Fixed Point Iteration and Nesterov;s Gradient Method]

Here's the link to the template: https://www.overleaf.com/articles/acceleration-in-fixed-point-iteration-and-nesterov-s-gradient-method/pksgtcxdcffq

Comment: That depends on the document class used. Most have font size options.

Comment: @Johannes_B, is there a way to identify the margin and font sizes used in this template: www.overleaf.com/articles/acceleration-in-fixed-point-iteration-and-nesterov-s-gradient-method/pksgtcxdcffq.

Comment: A few relevant questions: Margins: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50259/  Font size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155896/ Units: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113513/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, you're using the `article` document class. This is one of the most common general purpose LaTeX document classes.

- Assuming your TeX distribution is fully up to date, you're using v. 1.4n (2021/10/04) of `article.cls`.
- Since you do not appear to load this document class with any particular options, the default font family is `Computer Modern` and the default document font size is `10pt`.
- The default margin sizes depend in part on the size of the printer paper you employ. The two most common paper sizes for general document typesetting are `letterpaper` (aka "US Letter", 11in x 8.5in or 795.0pt x 614.3pt; used mainly (exclusively?) in North America) and `a4paper` (aka "A4 paper", 297mm x 210mm or 845.05pt x 597.51pt; used for printers just about everywhere else in the world).

  - Your TeX distribution is likely set up to choose one or the other of these two options as the default paper size. Don't assume, though, that just because your computer and any attached printer may be based somehwere in Europe, say, that the option `a4paper` is in effect by default for your TeX distribution. I, for one, am based in Europe, but I've deliberately chosen `letterpaper` as the default paper size, mainly because the overwhelming majority of my scientific collaborators happen to be based in North America. (In case you're curious: I'm an economist. Not having to re-format LaTeX papers that we email each other back and forth across the Atlantic is a big time saver...)
  - The file `article.cls` also defines sizes for `a5paper`, `b5paper`, `legalpaper`, and `executivepaper`. If you load a package such as `geometry`, many more default paper sizes are defined for you to choose from.
- Assuming you're using the (basic) 10pt font size, we could next look into `size10.clo` -- I think "clo" stands for "class options" -- for further information about margins.

  - Unfortunately, I cannot in good conscience recommend you spend much time going through `size10.clo` (or, for that matter, `size11.clo` or `size12.clo`). They're chock-full of information, but they aren't exactly easy to parse.
  - Suffice it to say that the default value of `\textwidth` (the width of the text block) is `345pt` -- this works out to `4.774in`, or `12.125cm` -- if either `letterpaper` or `a4paper` is in effect. You may verify this directly, by the way, by executing `\the\textwidth` somewhere in your test document.
  - The default value of `\textheight` may be calculated from a knowledge of `\paperheight` and the default settings of `\topmargin` and `\bottommargin`. Long story short: as long as the `geometry` package is *not* loaded, the parameter `\textheight` works out to 550.0pt (aka 7.61in or 19.33cm) if `letterpaper` is in effect, and to 598.0pt (aka 21.02cm or 8.275in) if the option `a4paper` is in effect.
  - Thus, even though `\textwidth` is the same by default regardless of whether `letterpaper` or `a4paper` is in effect, this is not the case for `\textheight`: this parameter is ca 1.8cm *larger* if `a4paper` is in use.
- Unless the `twoside` document class option has been chosen (which isn't the case for the template document), the horizontal margins are symmetric. Thus, assuming `letterpaper` is in effect (for which `\paperwidth` equals `8.5in`), the left and right hand margins can be calculated by subtracting `\textwidth` from `\paperwidth` and dividing the result by 2: 1.863in. Calculating the value of `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin` for the case that `a4paper` is in effect is left as an exercise to the reader.
- If you're starting to think that the exposition used in the preceding bullet points is rather convoluted, you're not alone. I, for one, would *never* recommend that you manipulate the LaTeX parameters that govern the margins directly. Instead, I would strongly recommend that you employ the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to set the paper size and the margin widths or, equivalently, the values of `\textheight` and `\textwidth`.

Happy (La)TeXing!